# Interactive 2D videos on 3D object?

Tags: 2d

I want to put an illustration (2D) and add some interactive videos/GIFs (2D, part of the illustration) to it, it is possible to use a 3D object as a base for that illustration, all while keeping the interactive parts?

Comment: You can use videos as textures, like regular images. But you have to convert GIFs into video files or image sequences.

Comment: Is it possible to make those videos interactive? As in, they only play if you click on them?

Comment: What do you mean by interactive? Blender is not a game engine, elaborate your question so that we can understand what exactly you trying to achieve

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob in Blender, and it doesn't help that english isn't my first language; but: I was just wondering if it was possible to make an 3D base for an illustration, which you would be able to scroll around, and upon clicking on certain images, it would trigger a video (like, if there was a leaf, you could click on it and it would move). I know this can be done in 2D, but I was hoping there would be a way of putting this on a 3D, so you could "travel" around it.

Comment: As @Crantisz said, you are probably looking for a game engine. The game engine has been dropped since `2.8` but there is a fork called UPBGE thak kept the Blender game engine. What you want to do can probably be done with this.

Comment: What medium do you want to use? Where your interactive will be shown? Is that web site or application for android/iOS?